# How to send multiple ERC20 tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20, airdrop

There are about 2k ethereum addresses I'm supposed to send my ERC20 token to.
Doing this manually is a no no.
I've searched to and fro to no but most of the tutorials are not detailed enough.
So can someone show me a way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options:

1) Use a backend system (outside blockchain) which has access to an address which has enough tokens. The backend system then loops through the addresses and transfers the tokens.

2) Write a smart contract to which you assign required amount of tokens. The contract has a function to loop through given addresses and transfers tokens to those addresses from its balance.

Most likely the first approach is a lot easier and cheaper. With the second approach you have to send more data into the blockchain which costs you more. And the first approach is much easier to accomplish securely.